# Dbus-daemon using too much RAM

Tags: 10.04, system

Yesterday I discovered that dbus-daemon was taking from 10% to 30% of my RAM.
How can I reduce the amount of RAM being used?

Comment: hi, this dbus-daemon has really been making me run crazy for the last couple of months especially this last week. Been searching and posting in different forums and launchpad bugs but haven't got a reply, moreover, launchpad says it's fixed in the current release, which it it obviously not. I'm still a noob on ubuntu, i'm sorry, but i'll love to provide anything that you ask if anyone can help me. here's a 'part' of the output when i run dbus-monitor --session. http://paste.ubuntu.com/582745/

thanks a bunch guys

Comment: Try turning Rhythmbox off.

Answer (score 5):

dbus is a middle man communicating data between applications so something you have installed is using dbus more than it should or its also possible that there is something wrong with dbus if you can supply the output of this Command

```
dbus-monitor --session
```

easy way is to paste it at [pastebin.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/)
and add it to your question it should give us an Idea of what could be causing the problem.

Sorry if this isn't an answer just too much for a comment.

ps found these two forum posts which my lead you to the answer.

[dbus-daemon is consuming memory](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1472763)
[dbus daemon, loads of activity (slowing down machine)](http://art.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1437780)

Comment: Hi. I figured it out that the problem was conky. So i turned it down and everything is OK now. But i am wondering if there is any way that i use conky and that dbus-daemon wouldn't consume so much RAM. Thx for answer

Comment: That's probably a good question for the conky guys at https://launchpad.net/~conkyhardcore/+archive/ppa but probably the ram usage will go up depending on how many info displays you are showing plus as conky is script based there is probably a way of reducing the ram usage unfortunately I'm not a Hardcore conky nutcase ;)

Comment: hehe, i am not hardcore conky nutcase either :))  I will ask them on launchpad. Thx for your help.